# Text field animation in android

Tags: android, textview

Can someone tell me how do I create a animation effect in android. I want a `TextView` say Name , Age, Sex move from left to a particular position on screen. For eg: like if the `TextView` comes moving from left end of the screen.These fields are vertically arranged on a linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

make a new xml in res/anim/ named as ltor.xml with the contents

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="700"/>
       </set>
```

give the following attribute in the view you want to animate.

`android:animation="@anim/ltor"`

Comment: Can u give a proper example I am not able to understand it from above code.Thnx

Comment: The method startAnimation(Animation) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int).   This is the following eror that is shown if i try above solution.